# What is Puzzle Overflow?

Tags: support, questions, clone

Just came across this site: http://www.puzzleoverflow.com

It looks exactly the same as a Stack Exchange site. It doesn't seem to have any connection with SE, though, and it's not mentioned on Stack Exchange or anything.

Comment: FWIW, Puzzle Overflow is also mentioned in this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones/64742#64742

Comment: Ack, I noticed in the half-second between hitting "Save Edits" and the page actually refreshing that I clobbered someone. Sorry!

Comment: You should ask [George Stocker](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/16587/george-stocker) - He's got [an account on Puzzle Overflow.](http://www.puzzleoverflow.com/users/4/george-stocker)

Comment: @Peter Yup. I answered below.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at its source:

```
<meta name="generator" content="StackExchange 0.9 (20100413135304-37b86aed49ad)">
```

I'd say it's a SE-1.0 site <sub>(or someone asking for a law suit)</sub>

Comment: Can't seem to find it in the SE 1.0 site list: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-1-0-sites

Comment: @Piskvor: I'm not certain that list is complete, SE 1.0 allowed for private usage too. Maybe someone from the team can clarify this

Comment: Ah, good point. We're kind of guessing here. OTOH, the links in non-obvious places point to StackOverflow.com, there is no contact info, no legal info, nothing. (the even FAQ has "we don't run %(sitename), you do"). I'm guessing "clone"; added to the SO clones list: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones

Comment: If it runs on the engine, it's almost certainly not an unauthorized clone.  I'm with Tobias, it's more likely a SE1.0 site that just needs to be added to the list.

Answer (score 2):

It is a StackExchange site. In addition to checking the metadata, you can also visit it at http://puzzleoverflow.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

It was a Stack Exchange 1.0 puzzle site. It was a lot of fun and I think it'd have a place as part of a [larger Stack Exchange built around Interviewing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13418/interviewing). But There isn't one of those yet.