# Posts linked in deleted answers still show up under "Linked"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-answers, linked-questions

E.g. see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64730/what-is-puzzleoverflow).

[image: screenshot of deleted answer]

Comment: I guess it's status-bydesign... in that case, please feel free to retag this a [feature-request] to show these links only to 10k users who can also see the deleted answers.

Comment: Actually, since @Popular linked that question in a comment over there, the link doesn't really serve any illustration anymore, either.

Comment: @Grace, I only did it to make your screenshot that much more valuable.

Comment: @Grace the screenshot plus the timeline still speak for themselves I guess

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The linked / related questions are rebuilt every 30 days, so at that time any deleted links will be culled.