# Automatic "linked questions" bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, linked-questions

I can't be sure this report isn't a duplicate, but if it is, I apologise.

I recently posted the meta(`!.SO`) question [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/954) containing a link to another one at the beginning.  Now, detecting this, the software gleefully added a "Linked" section to the right-hand column... to, uh, a [question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/951) unrelated to my [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7367)?

Curious as I am how that question was picked, can teh codez for parent and meta sites be made to ignore or recognize links to the other?

Comment: @PM2Ring Another user already helped me:  We have to leave blank lines above and below the paragraph that contains the hyperlink. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linked questions pop up when the links are intra-site, not inter-site.

The Math.SE public facing side would be one site, the horrors of Math.Meta another.
They won't cross-pollinate the Linked questions sidebar of each other.

Also, there may be a [deleted answer or comment among the two posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64743/posts-linked-in-deleted-answers-still-show-up-under-linked) that once referred to the question that does show up.