# Referenced topic isn't automatically shown in the Linked section on the ELL site?

Tags: discussion, linked-questions

This is my first time to report a bug in SE net. So I am not sure if I did it in the right way.

About 1 hour ago, I created a question ([When the expression "I shall be coming to see you ..." would be used?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/240039/109190)), which shows the bug I'm referring to.

The bug is that because that post links to another post (i.e. [Does bridge actually refer to the part on which pedestrians and vehicles move on in everyday English?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/239938)) therefore I'd expect that other post to show in the "Linked" section -- but it doesn't.

---

Updated: I posted a [new one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/240050/109190) on ELL at 9:15 PM March 10, 2020 (UTC). Everything works as expected.

---

I guess the following part could be ignored.

I am also not sure if I used the right term to refer to the feature.

Each time I link a post from the same SE site, SE would automatically add a link at the right side of the page, shown as below.

[image]

A few hours ago, this feature still worked well, until just now.

I noticed there was an update very recently. After which the handy feature is gone. I suspect it is by design. So, I come here to post a question.

While I was writing, similar questions showed up, one of them is a 
9-year-old post [Automatic "linked questions" bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68582/714660). I put it here for reference, in the meanwhile, I tried to use it if the feature works well on this site (meta.stackexchange.com).

Apparently, the feature works well here. So, I re-edit this post again to update.

Comment: There were issues a couple of days ago with the linked panel: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394157/where-is-the-linked-tab/394158#394158

Comment: Confirmed. Tested: When I add the link in a comment to the question it appears in linked, and remains after deletion.