# No notification received for new answer

Tags: bug, answers, notifications

I posted a bug just now ([Referenced topic isn't automatically shown in the Linked section on the ELL site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344928/714660)) and then I guess I encountered another one.

Usually, after someone else answered my question, the SE would send me a notification.

about 8 mins ago, a nice guy answered one of my questions on ELL (["sound natural" vs. "to be natural"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/240082/109190)). I haven't received that notation since.

On the other hand, I did receive other notifications, which are for some comments on the bugged question and another question.

[image]

Comment: Just to note that I experienced [the same thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344960/why-didnt-i-get-notification-of-this-answer-in-my-inbox).