# Why didn't I get notification of this answer in my inbox?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, notifications, stackexchange.com, global-inbox

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60623319/getting-custom-post-type-data-including-acf-with-timber) to SO recently and by chance I noticed I had [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60623887/472501); however I only noticed this answer by chance - I never received a notification in my inbox like I always do.

I thought I may have missed it, but I checked my inbox and it is not showing there whatsoever - my last notification is from Feb 19th.

Is there a reason I wasn't notified or is there some kind of issue here?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the same issue; in fact, I encountered it too yesterday.

Comment: @Glorfindel Same issue as what?

Comment: As the linked (duplicate) question ...

Comment: @Glorfindel Oh, I wasn't seeing the duplicate section notice until I reloaded the page.