# Appearance of new meta posts in diamond dropdown seems broken

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, per-site-meta, stack-exchange-button

Last night someone posted a new question on Science Fiction & Fantasy Meta. I'm a moderator on Science Fiction & Fantasy, but this post didn't appear in the diamond dropdown menu which is supposed to show all new meta posts as they appear.

[image]

Comment: Is it applicable to your co mods also?

Comment: @Pandya I see the same problem as a fellow mod on SFF -- no blue diamond and no post in the dropdown.

Comment: Related? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344939/no-notification-received-for-new-answer