# How can we help mark irrelevant links as unhelpful?

Tags: support, linked-questions

I was looking at a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009295/how-to-detect-the-sim-card-change-in-android-phone) today on Stack Overflow and there was a link in the sidebar to some other question/answer that was completely irrelevant.  The original question was about detecting SIM card changes on an android phone, but the ["Linked"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872117/is-it-possible-to-determine-if-the-sim-phone-number-has-changed?lq=1) response was specific to iOS.  There were no common tags for either discourse.

Is there a way for the community to shape the linking algorithm at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove questions that appear in the Linked section of the sidebar by removing links to those questions. Either in the comments, answers or the question itself.

[Then wait 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64743/posts-linked-in-deleted-answers-still-show-up-under-linked/79317#79317).

Also, [the links are bi-directional](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48076/whoa-what-is-this-linked-thing), so if it's linked back from a question on the sidebar, you have to remove traces from there as well.

Comment: I'm ok with the waiting 30 days, but I don't feel the need to bi-directionally police links.